# Error during installation of a binutils Canadian Cross-Compile

Tags: android, cross-compilation

I am trying to compile binutils for Android using the Android NDK, so I installed the the NDK using the guide found [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) (specifically "Advanced method") and I proved it working by compiling Lua with it successfully.

Here are the steps I followed:

```
export NDK=/path/to/ndk
export SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-23/arch-arm
$NDK/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch=arm --api=23 --install-dir /tmp/android-toolchain
export PATH=/tmp/android-toolchain/bin:$PATH

mkdir build-binutils
cd binutils
export TARGET=arm-linux-androideabi
export HOST=$TARGET
export BUILD=x86_64-linux
../binutils-2.27/configure --host=$HOST --target=$TARGET --build=$BUILD --with-sysroot=$SYSROOT --disable-nls --disable-werror
make
make install
```

`make install` fails with the following output:

```
This is not dpkg install-info anymore, but GNU install-info
See the man page for ginstall-info for command line arguments
./libtool: line 1118: arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib: command not found
make[5]: *** [install-bfdlibLTLIBRARIES] Error 127
make[4]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-bfd] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Note that running `arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib` works fine:

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
Usage: arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib [options] archive
 Generate an index to speed access to archives
 The options are:
  @<file>                      Read options from <file>
  --plugin <name>              Load the specified plugin
  -D                           Use zero for symbol map timestamp
  -U                           Use actual symbol map timestamp (default)
  -t                           Update the archive's symbol map timestamp
  -h --help                    Print this help message
  -v --version                 Print version information
arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib: supported targets: elf32-littlearm elf32-    bigarm elf32-little elf32-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

What is the correct method for installing a cross-compiled toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit: I was actually running `sudo make install` and not `make install`, so the temporary PATH was ignored because of user switching. Solution was to run `sudo su` and then update the PATH and re-run `make install`

Comment: Thanks so much. I was running an unprivileged build, but inside `proot`, and so the system behaved as if I was `root`, including the `PATH`. This helped me solve the mystery.